# How can I get the memory footprint of a specific key in redis?

Tags: redis

I'm new to Redis. How can I get the memory footprint of a specific key in redis?

```
db0

  1) "unacked_mutex"
  2) "_kombu.binding.celery"
  3) "_kombu.binding.celery.pidbox"
  4) "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
```

I just  want to get the memory footprint of one specific key like `"_kombu.binding.celery"` , or one specific db like `db0` , how can I get it?

redis_version: `2.8.17`

Any commentary is very welcome. great thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running a very old version of redis. The `MEMORY` command is not available in that version, so there is no precise way of getting at this information. However, you can approximate this information using the `DUMP` command.

Simply call `DUMP _kombu.binding.celery` and save the results to a file. The result is some characters and escape sequences. When you load this file into an environment like node, you can look at the length of the string and multiply by 2 to get the number of bytes. This is not precise, but it will give you a generally close approximation.

Here's what you could do:

in Redis:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> hset c 123 456
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> dump c
"\r\x12\x12\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\xfe{\x03\xc0\xc8\x01\xff\t\x00\x10\xd4L \x908\x8b2"
```

in Node:

```
$ node
> a="\r\x12\x12\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\xfe{\x03\xc0\xc8\x01\xff\t\x00\x10\xd4L \x908\x8b2"
'\r\u0012\u0012\u0000\u0000\u0000\r\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000þ{\u0003ÀÈ\u0001ÿ\t\u0000\u0010ÔL 82'
> a.length
30
```

This is close to half of the actual amount that redis provides with `MEMORY USAGE`:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY USAGE c
(integer) 63
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Does DEBUG OBJECT `"_kombu.binding.celery" works?
`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `DEBUG OBJECT`, but the docs say that the command is meant for debugging redis itself. So, it's probably not good for userland actions.

Answer (score 2):

`MEMORY USAGE _kombu.binding.celery` would give you the number of bytes that a key and value require to be stored in RAM.

[Here](https://redis.io/commands/memory-usage) is the doc for the command.

Comment: thanks for your reply, tried  but got `(error) ERR unknown command 'MEMORY'` for my redis version is `2.8.17`

Comment: You could do `DEBUG OBJECT key1` instead. It returns the `serializedlength`, which I think is the size of the object when it is saved to the RDB file (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7649466/509710). Note that `DEBUG` commands are disabled for AWS ElasticCache.